# phonegap's blank template inappbrowser plugin issue

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

I have made a currency converter application using javascript as a fun project and I made it into apk file with phonegap build. The application can convert online and offline , and user must click first on the screen to choose whether online or offline. But the online part does not work when I click the button in my phone. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
    }


function offline() {
  window.location.assign("local/offline.html")
}
function online() {
  window.location.assign("http://invailor.000webhostapp.com/NewCurrency.html")
}

</script>

        
    </head>
    <body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> <!-- this does not even work since js is not in the blank app template -->
 <h1>Welcome to the currency converter</h1>
 <p> How do you want to use this app?</p>
  
 <input type="button" value="online" onclick="online()">
<a href=”#” onclick="window.open('http://invailor.000webhostapp.com/NewCurrency.html', '_blank', 'location=yes');">online</a>     
 <input type="button" value="Offline" onclick="offline()">


    </body>
```

My issue is that it seems inappbrowser and cordova plugins are not included in Phonegap Desktop's blank application template. I have this template from some years ago when I tested with another app and now I cannot get Phonegap Desktop to work on Windows 10 any more, it is just stuck on screen with spinning circle and does not start the server. As far as I can remember on the Phonegap's hello world template these plugins were included. If someone would provide me the Phonegap's 0.4.5 default hello world template I would appreciate it. It seems the one I found on the internet was missing files and I could not get it to work. Here is my project: [online currency converter zip](https://bayfiles.com/Hex4Xck6pf/online_currency_converter_zip)

Answer (score 0):

I found a Phonegap Desktop working version for Windows 10 , this is the link:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/releases/tag/0.2.3

From there I created new project and got everything to work!